# parse JSON function

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain to me how this parse function actually works?

```
function parseFlickrJson(jsonstring){
    var data=null;

    var jsonFlickrApi=function(d){
        data = d;
    }

    eval(jsonstring);

    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JSON is actually valid JavaScript. So all you need to 'decode' it, is to evaluate it as JavaScript (hence the `eval`). It's also using something known as JSONP http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP where more than just JSON is returned.

JSONP is basically JSON wrapped in a function call. The content of a JSONP response might be:

```
parseResponse({"Name": "Cheeso", Id : 1823, "Rank": 7})
```

What this means is that when you evaluate JSONP, it will attempt to call a function (in this example `parseResponse` and in your case `jsonFlickrApi`). This is why the `jsonFlickrApi` function must be defined before the `eval(jsonstring)` occurs.

Comment: so var jsonFlickrApI is not just a custom variable but an actual existing 'thing'? (sorry that must sound a little ignorant...i'm mainly used to Java)

Comment: the `var jsonFlickrApi = function(d) ...` is actually creating an anonymous function and storing a reference to it in `jsonFlickrApi` (so I suppose it's not really anonymous). `eval` evaluates a string as if it was source code. Since the response from the Flickr API includes a call to `jsonFlickrApi`, it's important that that function actually exists, or you'll get an exception.